# sqlalchemy check foreign key refer data exist before insert?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm new to the sqlalchemy and fastAPI. I wonder there is any way to check refer data automatically before inserting it. For example, I want to make sure that profile.user_id exists before adding a new profile, but I don't want to do it by myself. Is that possible? Below are my table settings.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    hashed_password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    create_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
    login_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())

class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_profile"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, )
    age = Column(Integer)
    country = Column(Integer)
    photo = Column(String, )
```

Answer (score 1):

What is missing in your mapped classes is a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html).

In ORMs, these relationships handle ensuring the foreign key exits and makes creating relationships much easier.

Also, if you want to set a default value on the SQL side (since you use `default=func.now()`), you should use the `server_default=func.now()` keyword argument. Otherwise, use the python side equivalent, `default=datetime.utcnow()`.

Finally, if your relationship is a one-to-one relationship, use the `uselist=False` keyword argument in the `User.profiles` relationship (also best to rename it `User.profile`).

```py
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    DateTime,
    ForeignKey,
    Integer,
    String,
    create_engine,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base, relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    hashed_password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    create_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow())
    login_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow())
    profiles = relationship(
        "Profile", back_populates="user"
    )  # add uselist=False if one-to-one


class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_profile"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    country = Column(Integer)
    photo = Column(String)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="profiles")


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True, future=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:

    ljmc = User(email="ljmc@stack.overflow", hashed_password="00ab")
    ljmc_profile = Profile(name="ljmc")

    ljmc_profile.user = ljmc

    session.add(ljmc)
    session.flush()
```

This emits:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        email VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        hashed_password VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        create_time DATETIME NOT NULL, 
        login_time DATETIME NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        UNIQUE (email)
)
CREATE TABLE user_profile (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR, 
        age INTEGER, 
        country INTEGER, 
        photo VARCHAR, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user (id)
)
INSERT INTO user (email, hashed_password, create_time, login_time) VALUES ('ljmc@stack.overflow', '00ab', '2023-01-17 10:11:48.250845', '2023-01-17 10:11:48.250959')
INSERT INTO user_profile (user_id, name, age, country, photo) VALUES (1, 'ljmc', None, None, None)
```